# Change squid log file rotate

Tags: squid

I want to create squid log file every hour, not every day.

My log file is about to 1GB.

Is it possible to generate access.log file every hour?

Comment: Did you do any research for resolving the issue by yourself?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this it fails to demonstrate the minimum necessary prior work.

Comment: Hello. Of course I tried lots of things include "squid -k rotate" but it didn't work. It was showing me some warnings. I googled it and tried to do few things (inc: ADD acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/8 line but didnt work.

Comment: If I remove all manager and localhost acls and try rotate -k, it shows no error but no new logs also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squid writes to a number of log files unless you disable them in squid.conf. You must periodically rotate the log files to prevent them from consuming too much disk space. Squid places a lot of importance on log files and exits with an error message when it can't write to them. To keep disk space consumption under control, use the following command in a cron job:

```
squid -k rotate
```

For example, this crontab entry rotates the logs every 24 hours, at 4 A.M.:

```
#m h dom mon dow   command
0 4 * * * /usr/local/squid/sbin/squid -k rotate
```

This command does two things. First, it closes the currently open log files. Then, it renames the cache.log, store.log, and access.log files by appending a numeric extension. For example, cache.log becomes cache.log.0, cache.log.0 becomes cache.log.1, and so on, up to the value of the logfile_rotate option.

Squid keeps only the last logfile_rotate versions of each log file. The older versions are simply removed during the renaming process. If you want to keep more copies, you need to increase the logfile_rotate limit or write some custom scripts that move the log files to a different location.

[Source, first search result of "squid log rotation"](https://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Squid.+The+definitive+guide/Chapter+5.+Running+Squid/5.10+Rotating+the+Log+Files/)

[Crontab Quick Reference](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Comment: I tried that before but I tought It's deleting old logs. Thank you so much! When I run the command, it shows me this and there is no new log file. I made few reseearchs but couldnt figure it out. Squid works great without problem. ------WARNING: Netmasks are deprecated. Please use CIDR masks instead. ------WARNING: IPv4 netmasks are particularly nasty when used to compare IPv6 to IPv4 ranges. ------WARNING: For now we will assume you meant to write /32

Comment: I solve the problem after I add 'logfile_rotate 9' line. Thx.